# Force octave to use command line

Tags: bash, ubuntu, octave

Before upgrading my ubuntu install to 16.04 invoking 'octave' would open the octave interpreter, useful as a powerful calculator.

Now, typing octave opens the octave gui. I need to type 'octave --no-gui' to get my interpreter back.'

Why does this happen? How can I restore 'octave' opening the interpreter?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Defaults change over time depending on typical usage.  To fix it, just:

Add an alias to your ~/.bashrc

```
alias octave="octave --no-gui"
```

Now source your file to enable it.

```
source ~/.bashrc
```