# How do I set traditional/braindead mode in octave 4

Tags: macos, octave

Before Octave 4.x, I would just run Octave from the CLI so I would do this:

```
octave --traditional
```

Now that GUI mode is the default when running Octave, I just start Octave from a shortcut (I'm using OS X Yosemite).

Is there a command or something I can put on `.octaverc` to switch to traditional mode?

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37739493/force-octave-to-use-command-line

Comment: If you want to use the GUI just edit your shortcut and add "--traditional"

Answer (score 2):

You need set a number of variables in octaverc:

```
PS1                             = ">> "
PS2                             = ""
beep_on_error                   = true
confirm_recursive_rmdir         = false
crash_dumps_octave_core         = false
disable_diagonal_matrix         = true
disable_permutation_matrix      = true
disable_range                   = true
fixed_point_format              = true
history_timestamp_format_string = "%%-- %D %I:%M %p --%%"
page_screen_output              = false
print_empty_dimensions          = false
save_default_options            = "-mat-binary"
struct_levels_to_print          = 0
warning('off', 'Octave:abbreviated-property-match')
warning('off', 'Octave:fopen-file-in-path')
warning('off', 'Octave:function-name-clash')
warning('off', 'Octave:load-file-in-path')
warning('off', 'Octave:possible-matlab-short-circuit-operator')
```

That is equivalent of -traditional. See https://www.gnu.org/software/octave/doc/v4.0.1/Command-Line-Options.html for other possible settings that could be also used with traditional. Should also work for Octave 5.2.

Answer (score 1):

The simple solution is to create a Bash script that calls `octave --traditional`, and link that from your start menu. The file could look like this:

```sh
#!/usr/bin/env bash
octave --traditional
```

You could call this file `octave_traditional.sh` and put it somewhere under your Octave directory, or in your user's `bin` directory, or anywhere you want. Do make sure to set its permissions correctly:

```sh
chmod a+x octave_traditional.sh
```

Answer (score 0):

By the time it reads the .octaverc file it is alrteady too late.

Try running Octave as "octave --no-gui"

Comment: This is not the answer. His question is not about starting without GUI. It's about starting Octave with specific command-line options (`--traditional`) now that he uses a shortcut instead of starting via the command line.